# Find button element using Selenium/Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to locate a button on the following page - https://www.dukascopy.com/swiss/english/marketwatch/sentiment/

[The button I am trying to locate is the Liquidity providers button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNHzL.png)

I have tried using both the xpath and full xpath in driver.find_element_by_xpath(...) but it does not seem to locate the button at all. I have also tried all other find_element methods but to no avail.

I get the following error while using Xpath

> ```
> raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id=":1"]"}
> (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.97)
> ```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hi, it would be nice you could create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it would help people to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, it's not a button at all. It's a div. Secondly, its inside an iframe. Elements inside iframes or frames are not present in the main top level document. You must switch to see them. Something like this will work.

```
# get the iframe element
iframe = driver.get_element_by_tag_name('iframe')
# switch to it
driver.switch_to_frame(iframe)
# with the new frame active locate the element
liquidity_customers = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='Liquidity consumers']").click()
# switch back to top level of document
driver.switch_to_default_content()
```

Comment: no problem. it looks like those buttons just sort and you probably dont need to click them once inside the iframe it looks like all data is available without clicking any buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the page the only place that "Liquidity providers" is used is in the area you want, so,

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Liquidity providers')]")
```

Note: that this will return a list of elements, you want the only one in the list.

Comment: Hi, it does find an element but it does not seem to be the actual button/div i want as it produces an error again.

The error : selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <b>...</b> is not clickable at point (394, 11)